# How to select specific percentage of items from a vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have used `datasample()` and `randsample()` to select specific no. of items randomly from a vector. But I have to specify the no. of items explicitly. Is there any way to *specify percentage* instead?

Comment: Why can't you do `n = floor(% * N)`, where `n` is the number of items you have to specify, `%` is the percentage you want, and `N` is the total number of elements in the vector? This seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: @Wolfie  thanks it worked, please post it as answer so that I may mark it correct

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily convert between the *percentage* of data you want, and the *number* which is required by the functions you want to use...

```
n = floor( pct * N );
```

Where `n` is the number of items you have to specify, `pct` is the percentage you want to input (between 0 and 1), and `N` is the total number of elements in the vector.

You could use a different rounding function to `floor` (`ceil`/`round`), but `floor` is a good go-to so that you protect against requesting `n > N` elements due to numerical error or otherwise.